# Difference between Input::flash() and Session::flash() in Laravel 4

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, what is the difference between `Input::flash()` and `Session::flash(Input::all())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much difference, the former is a convenience method for the commonly needed task of storing the user's input in a session in order to repopulate the form if validation fails, for example.